# Confusion regarding string and escape characters

Tags: c#, escaping

suppose there is a string created like:
string s="This \n is new staring";

Above code we have got a \n which is a new line character which can be escaped either via an @ before the double quotes or by using \.

The confusion is my mind is that:

a. suppose this value is taken from a input box into the code then the \n get treated as normal string (automatically gets \n) and not new line character.

b. same if we assign the textbox value to a multiline textbox or label, the value gets treated as \n and is output as \n and not newline.

Is there any reference for this concept please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape characters are processed at *compile time*. This means that the compiled version of your program does not contain any escape characters.

Same goes for the `@""` notation: it just changes the way you can supply data for the string while writing your program, and is not included in your compiled program.

Data entered in a text box does not undergo escape character processing, so entering `\n` really is a string containing the characters `'\'` and `'n'`.

Comment: We are receiving data from another application (not .net) into our .net WCF service. The data contains csv values, separated by newline character. So, will the text be received as \n? and then we have to process this based on \n, and remove the \n or split the data on \n and store it in array?

Comment: The whole concept that `\n` means something special, does not exist after your code is compiled. Newline characters will simply be newline characters.

Comment: Suppose the 3rd party app sends text data containing 'Hello\nWorld' then will .NET interprete it as new line or '\n'?

Comment: For example lets say the .net writes the data received ('Hello\nWorld') from the 3rd party app into a file. Then, will the \n appear in file or a new line appear?

Answer (score 1):

The basics:

In memory you may have these bytes:

```
0x41, 0x42, 0x0a, 0x00
```

in decimal the same memory sells read as

```
65, 66, 10, 0
```

If *interpteted* as ASCII characters you have

```
'A', 'B', Newline, EndOfString
```

If you want to *express* these in source code, you may write:

```
string s = "AB\n"; // note: 0x00 is appended automatically
```

The compiler will do all the conversions and end up with the bytes in the first example. So "\n" is just a way to include the special chars `Newline` / Byte 0x0A in a string in a convenient way.

If you receive something from another application, through a file or a socket or whatever, you in fact receive **Bytes**, which your code may *interpret* in one of the ways explained above.

Please note: In .Net we have UTF strings, where each character in fact uses 16Bit/two Bytes, so the above explanation is good for C but not *exactly* true for C#. The basic principles are the same however.